# Selecting a distinct user from column using innerjoin MSSQL 2005 and VBscript

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic, distinct

Using Microsoft SQL 2005 and VBscript.

I'm making a message section for a website. I have a table named mail. Columns are messageid, sender, receiver, body, and created. Messageid, sender and receiver are all BIGINT data types. The body column is nvarchar(max) data type. The created is a datetime data type.

For this example lets say the user John has a userid of 100.

I'm trying to isolate the distinct users who have sent John messages OR have received message from John AND order the users by the time from the created column (or by the messageid). My query that I tried either fails or gives me the same user more than once.

This query:

```
SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT otherperson FROM ("
SQL = SQL & "SELECT DISTINCT sender AS otherperson, messageid from message where message.receiver= '100' ORDER BY messageid DESC "
SQL = SQL & "UNION "
SQL = SQL & "SELECT DISTINCT receiver AS otherperson, messageid from message where message.sender= '100' ORDER BY messageid DESC ) results "
SQL = SQL & "ORDER BY messageid"
```

Gives an error: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

```
SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT otherperson, messageid FROM ("
SQL = SQL & "SELECT DISTINCT sender AS otherperson, messageid from message where message.receiver= '100' ORDER BY messageid DESC "
SQL = SQL & "UNION "
SQL = SQL & "SELECT DISTINCT receiver AS otherperson, messageid from message where message.sender= '100' ORDER BY messageid DESC ) results "
SQL = SQL & "ORDER BY messageid"
```

ALSO gives an error: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

```
SQL = "SELECT otherperson FROM ("
SQL = SQL & "SELECT DISTINCT sender AS otherperson from message where message.receiver= '100' "
SQL = SQL & "UNION "
SQL = SQL & "SELECT DISTINCT receiver AS otherperson from message where message.sender= '100' ) results "
```

This query DOES work and gives me the distinct users that have received messages from John and have sent messages to john BUT I cant order by the message times for each distinct user.

You can use messageid (this is a unique number incremented by 1) or by created (this is a column with a datetime data type)

Can anyone help with this?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

I think the first thing you need to fix is the fact that there is no `messageid` field to order by.  You only have one field coming from your table created through the two SELECT statements.

Also, you have two parenthesis that are not needed.  Both look like this:

```
WHERE (message.
```

These are throwing off your query.

Finally, and the real issue here, you have ORDER BY statements inside your sub-query (`ORDER BY messageid DESC`), which you cannot do.  Remove these statements and you will fix this compiler error.

Delete these two order by statements, change your order by or add that column, and fix your parenthesis and you will be good to go.

Your final statement should look like this:

```
SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT otherperson, messageid FROM ("
SQL = SQL & "SELECT DISTINCT sender AS otherperson, messageid from message where message.receiver= '100'  "
SQL = SQL & "UNION "
SQL = SQL & "SELECT DISTINCT receiver AS otherperson, messageid from message where message.sender= '100' ) results "
SQL = SQL & "ORDER BY messageid"
```

Comment: sorry. i had already removed them, i forgot to update when i posted the message

Comment: @Patriotec - I updated my answer.  The root issue is the ORDER BY statements inside your sub-query.  Remove these two and fix your final ORDER BY to have a field to order on and you will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are two redundant parenthesizes.
This is how your query looks now:

```
SELECT DISTINCT otherperson 
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT sender AS otherperson from message where (message.receiver= '100'
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT receiver AS otherperson from message where (message.sender= '100'
) results
ORDER BY messageid
```

Just remove `(` before `message.receiver` and `message.sender`.

[EDIT] Remove the very top `DISTINCT`. It is redundant. `UNION` will not return duplicate values, no need to do extra distinct.

If you really needed `DISTINCT`, you could replace `ORDER BY messageid` with `ORDER BY 1` - order by the first column.

Comment: sorry. i had already removed them, i forgot to update when i posted the message